# Get ID of clicked on element in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the ID of an element I click on.
I put the function in the onclick element, like this:

```
<a id="myid" class="first active" onclick="markActiveLink();" href="#home">Home</a>
```

And this is in the function:

```
function markActiveLink() {   
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
}
```

This doesn't work, as it says it isn't defined.
Does it really forget about the ID, do I have to type it in the onclick?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try: `onclick="markActiveLink(this);"` and

```
function markActiveLink(el) {   
    alert($(el).attr("id"));
}
```

Comment: +1. This is it. `this` keeps its original scope. If you define it somewhere besides the element itself, `this` is not the element.

Comment: This was great. You got me to the answer I needed.  However, just want to mention a point.  Since el is the element, I believe all you have to do is do alert(el.id).  Tried it in 2015 chrome works fine.  Maybe it didn't work like that in past -- I know this is an older post. Just mentioning this to help current readers.

Answer (score 10):

why using an inline handler? Move to unobtrusive js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myid').bind('click', function(){
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah, that is a better way to deal with it.

Answer (score 9):

You have to pass the element to the function. JS itself isn't smarter than you :)

html:

```
<a id="myid" class="first active" onclick="markActiveLink(this);" href="#home">Home</a>
```

js:

```
function markActiveLink(e) {   
    alert(e.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `$(this)` because it does accidentally return the element you added the bind. When you click on an inner element, it also returns the outer element.

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">

    </div>
</div>
```

You better use the following appearance:

```
$("#outer").bind('click', function(e) {

    if(e.target.id === "inner")
    {
        alert("you clicked the inner element");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("you clicked the outer element");
    }
});
```

You can find a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vqab7jdo/1/

Answer (score 0):

I try all the ways, spend almost 2 hours and finally found the best way I prefer
try it:

```
< div onclick="div_Clicked(this.id)" id="some"/>
```

```
    function div_Clicked(itemName) { alert(itemName); }
```