# Find the element clicked class with a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have an issue with class and ajax :

Hi have several .megavideo div on my page.

```
  <div class="megavideo">
    <img alt="video" src="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/6TDQOEATSik/hqdefault.jpg">
    <a href="#nolink" onclick="javascript:play('note', 33);">
      <div class="maxiplay">
        <div class="titremaxiplay">
          CLICK TO PLAY
        </div>
        <img class="play" alt="play" src="kit/play.png">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Inside the div, there a link with a javascript function.
This javascript function goal is to refresh the .megavideo div around the link (and just that one)

My function :

```
function play(what, who){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",   
        url: "launchvideo.php",
        data: "what="+what+"&who="+who,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
        $(".megavideo").html(html);
      }
    });
}
```

For now, logically the function refresh every .megavideo divs.
How can i use (this) on my function to target only the .megavideo link parents ?

The closest answer i found here is that : [Get ID of clicked on element in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952767/get-id-of-clicked-on-element-in-function)
But it's not exactly what i'm looking for.

Thanks everyone !
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="megavideo">
    <img alt="video" src="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/6TDQOEATSik/hqdefault.jpg" /> 
    <a href="#nolink" onclick="play(this, 'note', 33);">
        <div class="maxiplay">
            <div class="titremaxiplay">
                CLICK TO PLAY
            </div>
            <img class="play" alt="play" src="kit/play.png"/>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

and

```
function play(el, what, who) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "launchvideo.php",
        data: "what=" + what + "&who=" + who,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $(el).closest(".megavideo").html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

**HTML**

```
<a href="#nolink" onclick="javascript:play(this,'note', 33);">
```

**JS**

```
function play(that,what, who){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",   
        url: "launchvideo.php",
        data: "what="+what+"&who="+who,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
        $(that).closest(".megavideo").html(html);
      }
    });
}
```